# datagridview add row white font

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a datagridview, bound to a datasource with allowUserToAdd=True, a new blank row is added to end of rowset, when values in Add row are set, if user tabs off datagridview, it appears the data in row is lost but actually the font is white as when you select row, background blue, font white but doesn't change back to black when tab off, anyone have a workaround or am I missing a setting?

Comment: Any events you coded?

Comment: please take a look at [ask].  can you share some code?

Comment: there's not much code, I wish I could just show a 5sec video, I load my grid by setting it's datasource to a locally defined datatable and I set the dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = true, a "new" row is appended to the end to allow users to add new rows, selected, it shows a blue background with white font, tab off and the text disappears, I discovered it's not changing colors, the text just disappears, tab back on and the text reappears